# When are @InjectView fields injected?

Tags: android, roboguice

Exactly when are an `Activity`'s fields that are annotated with `@InjectView` or `@InjectResource` injected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [A Simple Example](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample) on Roboguice's website, the members are populated by the time `super.onCreate()` has been called from the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
    @InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
    @InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
    @InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
    @InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
    @Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
    } 
}
```